# aggregation using setkey() and setindex returns different results

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(mpg)
```

I am using mpg data set and i want to compute maximum of variable `displ` by `manufacturer`, for cars that have `cyl = 4`.

**Setkeys method:**

```
setkey(df,cyl)
df[.(4),max(displ),keyby = manufacturer]

 manufacturer  V1
1:         audi 2.0
2:    chevrolet 2.4
3:        dodge 2.4
4:        honda 2.0
5:      hyundai 2.4
6:       nissan 2.5
7:       subaru 2.5
8:       toyota 2.7
9:   volkswagen 2.0
```

**setindex method:**

```
setindex(df,cyl)
df[.(4),max(displ),keyby = manufacturer ,on = 'cyl']

 manufacturer  V1
1:         audi 2.0
2:         audi 2.4
3:         audi 2.4
4:         audi 2.0
5:         audi 2.4
6:         audi 2.5
7:         audi 2.5
8:         audi 2.7
9:    chevrolet 2.0
```

Results are completely different. Should they be(I doubt)?
And if they must be different can you explain me how was calculations by `setindex` method performed?

Comment: Use the mtcars dataset that everyone has please. It has no audis, so you must be using something else... Regarding your problem: no, `setindex` will not change how `df[.(i)]` behaves, only how efficiently it is done -- read the docs.

Comment: @Frank Regarding the docs, I was looking at `?setkey`, which is what R retrieves with `?setindex`, and while `setindex` is present there, and appears in an example, it is not discussed at all.

Comment: More on `setindex` in the (very nice) `data.table` vignettes: [Secondary indices and auto indexing](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html)

Comment: @lmo edited. I used ggplot2 data set

Comment: Now I get it, thanks for adding the data. That does seem like a bug. Strangely, `df[.(4L), on='cyl'][, max(displ), by=manufacturer]` does work. The bug seems to be in "aggregation with on= vs a key" not setkey() vs setindex().

Comment: @Frank thank you for the comment. Maybe, we should inform creators of data.table packege about it. Because it seems really strange

Comment: Yeah, I agree. See https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support for instructions on filing an issue. They ask that you first test the issue on the development version (which I don't have installed here), among other things.

Comment: @Frank I will do, thank you:)